# How to install self signed certificate in IIS

Tags: visual-studio, iis-7.5

In my requirement, I need to make a self signed certificate. I have created that using "makecert.exe". 
But now I would like to know, how to install self signed certificate in IIS

Answer (score 5):

finally i got a step by step solution for creating and installing self signed certificate in IIS 
Please visit

http://www.neiland.net/blog/article/how-to-create-and-install-a-self-signed-ssl-cert-with-iis7/

Answer (score -1):

First, install certificate to personal store. Reffer to this article for guidance:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-portal-server-it/step-10-import-the-certificate-to-the-personal-certificate-store-for-the-index-management-server-HA001164773.aspx

After that, it should be available to select in website binding settings', when editing https entry.